# How to make TabTip.exe window Maximum when popup it

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to popup the Virtual Keyboard using below code:

```
var info = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\ink\TabTip.exe");
info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized;
var p = new Process();
p.StartInfo = info;
p.Start();
```

But the window still popups using last state window style, I want it always be Maximum, can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Window wnd = Application.Current.Windows.OfType<WindowType>().Where(w => w.Name.Equals("NameOfYourWindow")).FirstOrDefault();
```

and then set Window state with this

```
wnd.WindowState = System.Windows.WindowState.Maximized
```