# On-Screen Keyboard WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, keyboard, touch

I would like to invoke On-Screen Keyboard on button click in WPF. Is this possible and can I do this in C#/XAML?

I just want to have one button, that opens and another one to close the keyboard.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make WPF input control show virtual Keyboard when it got focus in touch screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19085931/how-to-make-wpf-input-control-show-virtual-keyboard-when-it-got-focus-in-touch-s)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will help you start the default On-Screen keyboard,hence there wont be any effort to create one.

```
Process.Start(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.System) + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + "osk.exe");
```

or just give :  `Process.Start("C:\\Windows\\System32\\osk.exe");`

or  `Process.Start("osk.exe");`

> Not : if platform is 64 bit debug in x64

osk = on screen keyboard !

Comment: What should I pass in Path.DirectorySeparatorChar ? Now I have an error "Syste.Windows.Shapes.Pth" does not contain a definition for 'DirectorySeparatorChar'